# Issue installing pymssql on m1 Mac

Tags: macos, apple-m1, pymssql

8 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/src/pymssql/_mssql.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds/lib -lsybdb -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/pymssql/_mssql.cpython-38-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql
Failed to build pymssql
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Above is a snippet of the output generated when I run 'pip3 install pymssql'. I've installed freeTDS and openSSL on homebrew, and I've tried a number of suggestions for similar issues and I'm still having issues.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me running M1 on Monterey 12.1, pip==22.0.3

I got this working using brew to install some required libraries:

```
brew install openssl
brew install FreeTDS
```

> openssl==3.0.1, freetds==1.3.9

Check the output when installing openssl as it specifies some environment flags you need to set so you can build and install pymssql properly. If you missed them then run:

```
brew info openssl
```

This is the message from brew info openssl which gives you the required commands to setup your environment variables:

```
openssl@3 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into 
/opt/homebrew, because macOS provides LibreSSL.

If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```